# AlamofireImage: How to set timeoutIntervalForRequest for af_setImage?

Tags: alamofire, alamofireimage

I am trying to use af_setImage to add images to UICollectionViewCell. Default timeoutIntervalForRequest is 60 seconds, but I should not wait the user more than 15 seconds. How can I set the custom timeoutIntervalForRequest for af_setImage? I tried below solutions, but they did not work.

```
let downloader = UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader
let configuration = downloader.sessionManager.session.configuration
configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 15
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15

af_setImage(withURL: url, completion: { (response) in
    // do stuff
})
```

Tried bottom solution to but didn't work

```
af_imageDownloader?.sessionManager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 15


af_imageDownloader?.sessionManager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15

                //tried this instead of af_setImage, this is not working too.
                af_imageDownloader?.sessionManager.request(URLRequest(url: url))
                    .responseJSON {
                        response in
                        switch (response.result) {
                        case .success:
                            // success
                            break
                        case .failure(let error):
                            // fail
                            break
                        }
                }
```